# AWS Lambda - Multiple objects uploaded to the same folder at same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I am using a script that does binary merge on files within a folder in AWS S3 whenever a new file gets uploaded. I have configured the Lambda trigger on the specific bucket on Object PUT to start merging the new file in folder with the existing files in same location. I have a scenario wherein I upload multiple files to the same folder at the same time and I am trying to understand how does Lambda merge files in this scenario. Can anyone please help me understand if the Lambda drops some files and triggers only once the script or will all the file creates trigger events and Lambda invokes the script to do merge on all files without dropping any?

Thanks