# AWS lambda multiple triggers at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I am new to using AWS Lambda and I have a requirement of merging files whenever new file is uploaded to folder in S3 bucket. I am using Lambda to invoke the code that merges new file with existing in S3 folder. I run into a scenario wherein files get uploaded to the same folder at same time. I am trying to understand how lambda handles multiple triggers in such cases.  Since multiple lambda requests are made at the same time will all these calls be executed synchronously? Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you explain how this is not a duplicate of the question you asked yesterday? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807207/aws-lambda-multiple-objects-uploaded-to-the-same-folder-at-same-time

Answer (score 0):

Each file uploaded to Amazon S3 will trigger a separate invocation of your Lambda function. There is no guarantee of the order of invocation, nor any guarantee that they will/will not run synchronously.

Your code must handle the possibility of them running in any order and possibly at the same time.